# ruby Savon use camelcase instead snake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon

i'm using [savon](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) gem for SOAP request building, i need `snake_case_elements`, but when i inspect it seems converted to `CamelCase`, am i missing something here? Here is a result

[image]

And how i did it:

```
    gls_url = 'https://adi-test.gls-poland.pl/adeplus/pm1/ade_webapi2.php?wsdl'
username = '612305291'
password = 'KGpartt2016'

@client = Savon.client(wsdl: gls_url,  
                      log: true,
                      logger: Rails.logger,
                      log_level: :debug,
                      pretty_print_xml: true)

ats = @client.call(:ade_login, message: {
                                          user_name: username, 
                                          user_password: password
                                        })
```

Comment: I guess you would want to erase the password. Also, don't paste images.

Comment: those are not real, already changed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`convert_request_keys_to`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/savonrb/savon/Savon%2FGlobalOptions:convert_request_keys_to) option to tell Gyoku how to convert the keys (if at all):

```
@client = Savon.client(wsdl: gls_url, convert_request_keys_to: :none)
```